# How to get the AmazonEC2 instances pricing details for different regions using boto3 in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Using **Aws bulk pricing API**, I can download the JSON for only one region so I am looking for getting the pricing detail for all the regions programmatically using Python.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like stated in the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/pricing.html):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('pricing')
response = client.describe_services(
ServiceCode='string',
FormatVersion='string',
NextToken='string',
MaxResults=123
```

)

You just need to have an env var with the region you want: `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`

Or you can set the region on the client itself:

```
client = boto3.client('pricing', region_name='us-west-2')
```

Without using boto:

```
my_region = "us-west-1"

url = f"https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/{my_region}/index.json"

result = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: I tried but it is aking me for credentials, I am not going to fetch any personal accounts details, I just want to get the pricing details for all the ec2 instances for different regions

Comment: Well, you can't do that using boto. But you should be able to do it using python requests, though.

Comment: As u told, I can use requests to get the details for only one region(us-east-1) 
 using the below URL https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/us-east-1/index.json  but not able to download the JSON for other regions

Comment: @DhandapaniSudhakar ok, I edited with the correct approach without boto.

Comment: Thank u so much, The mistake I did is, I just replaced the region in two places in the URL, I changed now it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

The below code will download the On-Demand and Reserved term instances pricing detail for different regions and store into my local system

```
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session
import requests
import json
import datetime


s = Session()
ec2AvailableRegions = []

def getAvailableRegionsForAService(serviceName):
    try:
        if serviceName == "ec2":
            global ec2AvailableRegions
            ec2AvailableRegions = s.get_available_regions(serviceName)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        print("Exception occured while fetching the available region for the service "+serviceName)

getAvailableRegionsForAService('ec2')

print("AmazonEC2 Available Regions : "+str(ec2AvailableRegions))


for region in ec2AvailableRegions:
    url = "https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/{0}/index.json"
    url = url.format(region)
    print(region)
    print(url)
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    response = requests.get(url)
    open('A:\Office\index'+region+".json", 'wb').write(response.content)
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
```